# For loop unexpected result

Tags: python

I was trying to make a function that takes an iterable as an argument and returns a list of the iterable given but without values that are the same next to each other.

e.g `my_function("1112334512")` would return `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2"]`.

I don't want it to remove duplicate values in the iterable, I want it to remove values that have their same value that is next to it. (e.g `"AAABA"` finished result would be `"ABA"`)

```
def my_function(iterable):
    iterable_1 = []
    for item in iterable:
        iterable_1.append(item)

    count = 0
    for item in iterable_1:
        # Tempoary count = count + 1
        if iterable_1[count] == iterable_1[count + 1]:
            iterable_1.pop(count)
        else:
            count += 1

    return iterable_1
```

My problem is that when I thought that this finally did it, the result of running `my_function("AAAABBBCCDAABBB")` returned: `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']`, which in theory did the correct thing up to D where I think the for loop ended.

My question is why?  And if it is not the loop then what is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me your method seems overly complex for the task. How about

```py
def my_function(iterable):
    result = []
    for e in iterable:
        if not result or result[-1] != e:
            result.append(e)
    return result
```

Comment: what does the `if not result` do?

Comment: does `if not result` mean if result doesn't have any item in it?

Comment: this is relevant only for the first element to be added. the first element must always be added - in just cannot be a duplicate. but result[-1]  would throw an index error if applied to the empty list. you could also write `if len(result) == 0 or result[-1] != e`

Comment: wait one more question... would `if not result` be the same as `if result != True` ?

Comment: no. try it in an interactive python console. python has this concept of "Truthy and Falsy Values". ```not [ ]``` becomes True. ```not ""``` becomes True as well. But this does not mean that [ ] equals True. Here is a good read about that topic: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Your code should like this, because iterable_1 changed after you pop a value out.

```
def my_function(iterable):
    iterable_1 = []
    for item in iterable:
        iterable_1.append(item)

    count = 0
    length = len(iterable_1)

    for item in range(length):
        try:
            if iterable_1[count] == iterable_1[count + 1]:
                iterable_1.pop(count)
            else:
                count += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass

    return iterable_1
```